# Android : how to create two arrow buttons on the screen?

Tags: android, layout, android-viewpager, android-sliding

I used to slide image viewpager. I have searched google but have not found a solution to create two buttons as in the image of each slide my pager. Is there any suggestion to my problem?

[image]

Comment: use a frame layout and put your arrow buttons and view pager in that frame

Comment: can I do this with viewpagerindicator?